# Times series homework: VAR model

Tags: time-series, self-study, vector-autoregression

I am looking for help in understanding my homework. I do not understand how to solve this problem. I hope some of you can help me on how to approach it or suggest some references. [image: VAR(1) pocess]

Comment: What have you done to attempt the question?

Comment: none of the questions seem to be about Granger causality

Comment: Suggestion 1: for the one-step-ahead forecast, $\mathbf{E}(y_t|I_{t-1})=\mathbf{E}(A y_{t-1}+u_t|I_{t-1})=\mathbf{E}(A y_{t-1}|I_{t-1})+\mathbf{E}(u_t|I_{t-1})=A y_{t-1}+0=A y_{t-1}$. Suggestion 2: regarding the stationarity condition, what about checking the roots of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What does yt=(1,2)' mean? I get confused. Thank you

Comment: In order to increase your chances of getting valuable replies, I'd suggest you to read: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info